# how to Insert multiple columns using PQputCopyData

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert two columns using  `PQputCopyData` with following code. But once it checks for the final result it shows error invalid byte sequence for encoding `UTF8` and data is not getting inserted into the database.
Both columns type is `character varying`. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
const char *buffer = "john,doe";

PGresult *res;

res=PQexec(conn,"COPY john FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',';");
cout<<buffer;
if(PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COPY_IN)
{
    cout<<"copy in not ok";
}
else
{
    if(PQputCopyData(conn,buffer,400) == 1)
    {
        if(PQputCopyEnd(conn,NULL) == 1)
        {
            PGresult *res = PQgetResult(conn);
            if(PQresultStatus(res) == PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
            {

            cout<<"done";
            }
                          else
                           {
            cout<<PQerrorMessage(conn);  Here I get the error invalid  byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"
                            }
        }

        else
        {
            cout<<PQerrorMessage(conn);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if(PQputCopyData(conn,buffer,400) == 1)
```

What's wrong is passing `400` instead of the actual size of the contents in `buffer`, making it send unallocated garbage after the real data. Use `strlen(buffer)` instead.

Also you want each line to finish with a newline, so `buffer` should be :

```
const char *buffer = "john,doe\n";
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I can insert multiple rows at a time?  I mean how should be the buffer structure ? Should I insert \n after every line in the buffer structure ?